# Hourly and annual optimization problem over matrix

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, scipy

Given a matrix like the following:

```
                                    A   User1   User2  …    User9
2015-01-01 01:00:00              8,72   58          3       2
2015-01-01 02:00:00             24,46   57          4       3
2015-01-01 03:00:00             37,02   62          4       2
…                               42,89   59          3       2
2015-12-31 23:00:00             46,80   59          4       2
```

I have a linear optimization problem where I have to distribute the amount in column A among a variable number of users, so that after the distribution I have as little left over as possible, and never give each user more than he can receive (more than what is in his column).

We have the following objective function, the following constraints, and the following bounds:

```
target_function = minimize[(User1 – beta1*A)+(User2-beta2*A)+…+(User9-beta9*A)]

constraint1 -> (User1 – beta1*A) >= 0
constraint2 -> User2 – beta2*A) >= 0
…
constraint9 -> (User9 – beta9*A) >= 0

beta1+beta2+…+beta9 = 1

beta1 = (0,1); beta2 = (0,1)…beta9=(0,1)
```

I have created a program that solves the above problem on an hourly, row-by-row basis, so I run 8,760 optimization problems, and get beta for each user and each hour. This is the optimal solution for my problem; the one that optimizes the allocation and minimizes the surplus.

However, I need to solve the same problem for an annual optimization. That is, I need to obtain a unique beta for each user for the whole year, which minimizes the annual; this is the best that could be done with Excel Solver, and I need to compare my solution with this one so that it can be seen that in each analysis my solution is more optimal (if I have 3 users, I would have 3 beta).

I have obtained the beta for **minimize[(sum(User1)-beta1*sum(A))+(sum(User2)-beta2*sum(A))+…+(sum(User9)-beta9*sum(A))**, but the solution with Solver on matrices and vectors is more optimal than on the total sum.

I pass my attempt, based on the problem solved for hourly optimization.

```
from datetime import
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import scipy.optimize as opt

ruta = 'C://Users//F1K3G//Documents//Py//PRUEBAS DE OPTIMIZACIÓN//'   

def f_objetivo(x):                                                    
    funcion_objetivo = 0
    for i in range(0, len(DF.columns)-2):
        funcion_objetivo = funcion_objetivo + (DF[DF.columns[i]]-x(i-1)*DF[DF.columns[0]])    
    return funcion_objetivo

def g1(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[1]]-x(0)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g2(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[2]]-x(1)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g3(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[3]]-x(2)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g4(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[4]]-x(2)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g5(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[5]]-x(4)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g6(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[6]]-x(5)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g7(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[7]]-x(6)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g8(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[8]]-x(7)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g9(x): return ((DF[DF.columns[9]]-x(8)*DF[DF.columns[0]]))
def g51(x):
    restriccion_betas = 0
    for i in range(0, len(DF.columns)-2):
        restriccion_betas = restriccion_betas + x[i]
    restriccion_betas = restriccion_betas - 1
    return restriccion_betas

def optimizar():
    semilla = []
    cons = list()                     
    bnds = list()

    for i in range(0, len(DF.columns)-2):
        semilla.append(1/(len(DF.columns)-2))
   
    for i in range(0, len(DF.columns)):      
        if i == (len(DF.columns)-2):
            restriccion = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': g51}
        else:
            funcion =  globals()["g"+str(i+1)]  
            restriccion = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': funcion}

        cons.append(restriccion)

    cons = tuple(cons)


    for i in range(0, len(DF.columns)-2): 
        bnds.append((0,1))

    bnds = tuple(bnds)

    result = opt.minimize(f_objetivo, semilla, bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

    print(result.message)
    print(result.x)
    print(f_objetivo(result.x))
return result.x

DF = pd.read_excel(
    ruta + 'BBDD.xlsx',
    sheet_name='CURVAS DE CONSUMO', skiprows=(0), usecols=range(0, 8), index_col=None, 
    keep_default_na=False, na_values=(""))                                 

beta = optimizar()
```

Here my DF to simulate for 24 hours:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: Timestamp('2015-01-01 01:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2015-01-01 02:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2015-01-01 03:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2015-01-01 04:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2015-01-01 05:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2015-01-01 06:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2015-01-01 07:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2015-01-01 08:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2015-01-01 09:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2015-01-01 10:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2015-01-01 11:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2015-01-01 12:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2015-01-01 13:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2015-01-01 14:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2015-01-01 15:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2015-01-01 16:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2015-01-01 17:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2015-01-01 18:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2015-01-01 19:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2015-01-01 20:00:00'), 20: Timestamp('2015-01-01 21:00:00'), 21: Timestamp('2015-01-01 22:00:00'), 22: Timestamp('2015-01-01 23:00:00'), 23: Timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00')}, 'A': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3:
0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 8.717808, 9: 24.463867999999998, 10: 37.023932, 11: 42.885964, 12: 46.796772, 13: 44.611467999999995, 14: 32.705155999999995, 15: 7.388567999999999, 16: 0.23240799999999995, 17: 0.0, 18: 0.0, 19: 0.0, 20: 0.0, 21: 0.0, 22: 0.0, 23: 0.0}, 'User 1': {0: 33.702759400187, 1: 33.702759400187, 2: 34.4354280827998, 3: 39.5641088610891, 4: 39.5641088610891, 5: 41.0294462263146, 6: 43.2274522741529, 7: 56.4154885611826, 8: 57.8808259264081, 9: 57.1481572437953, 10: 61.5441693394719, 11: 59.3461632916336, 12: 58.6134946090209, 13: 60.8115006568592, 14: 61.5441693394719, 15: 65.9401814351485, 16: 72.5341995786633, 17: 73.9995369438888, 18: 76.9302116743399, 19: 71.0688622134378, 20: 71.8015308960506, 21: 72.5341995786633, 22: 57.1481572437953, 23: 35.1680967654125}, 'User 2': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 4, 10: 4, 11: 3, 12: 4, 13: 3, 14: 4, 15: 4, 16: 3, 17: 4, 18: 4, 19: 3, 20: 4, 21: 4, 22: 3, 23: 4}, 'User 3': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 3, 10: 2, 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 3, 15: 1, 16: 2, 17: 3, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 2, 21: 2, 22: 2, 23: 2}, 'User 4': {0: 0.018, 1: 0.017, 2: 0.018, 3: 0.018, 4:
0.018, 5: 0.017, 6: 0.018, 7: 0.018, 8: 0.018, 9: 0.017, 10: 0.018, 11: 0.017, 12: 0.382, 13: 0.478, 14: 0.017, 15: 0.018, 16: 0.017, 17:
0.017, 18: 0.207, 19: 0.22, 20: 0.221, 21: 0.221, 22: 0.222, 23: 0.222}, 'User 5': {0: 12.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 10.0, 3: 10.0, 4: 10.0, 5: 10.0, 6: 10.0, 7: 10.0, 8: 10.0, 9: 15.0, 10: 18.0, 11: 20.0, 12: 21.0, 13: 22.0, 14: 21.0, 15: 22.0, 16: 21.0, 17: 26.0, 18: 22.0, 19: 18.0, 20: 19.0, 21: 18.0, 22: 19.0, 23: 18.0}, 'User 6': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 3, 9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 3, 12: 2, 13: 3, 14: 3, 15: 3, 16: 3, 17: 2, 18: 4, 19: 5, 20: 4, 21: 4, 22: 4, 23: 4}}
```

Comment: How can I attach XLSX to the post?

Comment: "How can I attach XLSX to the post?" The easiest way is to load the df into Python with `pd.read_excel(...)`, then do `df.head(N).to_dict()`. This includes N rows of data. If you paste that dictionary into your question, other people can load it easily with `pd.DataFrame(dictionary)`. You should set N so that it is large enough to show your problem, but not too large. More tips about making reproducible examples are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Can you tell us approximately how many users and time periods you expect to have in the full file? For example, scipy.optimize.minimize would probably be an inappropriate choice for 20K users or more.

Comment: I will not have more than 100 users.